# Import apache logs into elasticsearch using logstash in windows

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am very new to ELK stack and also commands in Windows cmd. I am trying to run below example into my windows machine. I have configured installed and configured ELK stack in my machine but does not know how to run below command in Windows cmd?

https://github.com/elastic/examples/tree/master/ElasticStack_apache

```
cat apache_logs | <path_to_logstash_root_dir>/bin/logstash -f apache_logstash.conf
```

I have tried below example but it is not working as expected. Please help.

```
type apache_logs >> C:\logstash-5.3.1\bin\logstash.bat -f apache_logstash.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 major solutions:

1. You can use mingw (also provided with git as "git bash") to use linux style commands with pipes. (see http://www.mingw.org/ )
2. Or you can change the **apache_logstash.conf** file, replacing the **input** section to ingest the apache log file directly instead of ingesting standard input and waiting for a pipe

actual:

```
input {  
  stdin { } 
}
```

replacement :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "<path_to_apache_log_file>"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
```